# Sequelize defaultValue not getting set

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Here is my model for a recipe table.  I am using mysql as the database, and the sequelize module.  If I leave the title, prep_time, or cook_time blank in the form it seems to skip the validation of allowNull and defaultValue and attempts to enter a '' (blank string) into the database.  Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('recipe', {
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT
        },
        ingredients: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT
        },
        instructions: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT
        },
        yield: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        prep_time: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: '0'
        },
        cook_time: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: '0'
        },
        image: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This can happen in two cases. First, if you have entered the `defaultValue` and `allowNull` later after defining the model then you need to resync the table with `sync({force: true)`.

Second, `AllowNull` and `defaultValue` will work if attributes like `title`, and prep_time are not provided to `create()`. for example `create({title:'',prep_time:''})` will fill empty values. but if you do `create({title:''}` then value of `prep_time` be set the `defaultValue`. Similary skipping `title` attribute will cause validation error.

But if you are doing `create(req.body)` and body has fields `title` and `prep_time`. then empty values will be entered.

Hope I made myself clear :)

Comment: That's exactly what is was.  Now I just need to pull those keys out of the object before it is submitted.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been years ago. But, this might be helpful for others. In this case, it should use validate notEmpty by Sequelize. Because HTML form by default pass in not null (empty string or '' or "" or ``), so there is no need to use validate notNull.

Here, i recommend people to read this:
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html

Sequelize will check orderly:

1. custom validation
2. built-in validation
3. constraint